# Are questions about predicting the future based on historical trends on-topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Lets say that I found a strong and clear historical trend. Could I then ask a question about the continuation of this trend in the future on this Q&A. I understand that the question needs to be asked using some special technique in order to avoid purely speculative answers, which are unwelcome on any Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say that questions about the techniques themselves would be fine but questions that could be re-phrased as "what if" would be closed.  It would take some skill to be able to remove the speculative nature from questions looking into the future.

Personally, I find that prediction models can tell you tomorrow why what they predicted yesterday did not happen today -- paraphrased.

Answer (score 1):

There is a futurology proposal covering such questions. I dont think opening the door here for prediction of future questions would be really productive and scientific. The futurlogy proposal is not about predicting future at all, but to discuss important factors and models for e.g. economic, industrial, climatic, technological forecasting. Anything else is crystall-ball rubbing and only a possible scenario with a distinct likelihood.

Just have a look and follow if interested, both proposals would imho profitate from each other

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34955/futurology

https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2768/are-historians-interested-in-future

Comment: It has been removed since.